# SoftLayer Api: How to get the currently consume of bandwidth packet traffic data?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a sl-vm which pay mode is monthly. I have buy it a bandwidth packet 250G. The sl website shows this vm's bandwidth usage is 34.18MB, as shown in flowing Fig:
 [image]

While, I use Softlayer_Virtual_Guest:getBandwidthTotal to get this vm's bandwith and get the result 45500302 which is not equals to  34.18MB.

Q1: Which bandwidth usage data is the real comsumption?
Q2: If the api I used is not correct, please show me the connect one.
Regard~

Comment: To correct an error： the website shows the total bandwidth is 46.35MB.  The api result is 45500302（B?）,  45500302/1024/1024 = 43.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the “IEEE notation: kilobyte = 1000 bytes”, it means that you need to do the following: `45500302/1000/1000 =45.5`.  There are some variations between UI and API values.

You can use this online tool:

http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/?input_amount=45500302&input_units=bytes&notation=ieee

#### References:

[Projected Data for Bandwidth in Softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286157/projected-data-for-bandwidth-in-softlayer)

[Bandwidth summary per server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308040/bandwidth-summary-per-server)

[SoftLayer REST API get Bandwidth Data By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014415/softlayer-rest-api-get-bandwidth-data-by-date)

[Bandwidth summary per server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308040/bandwidth-summary-per-server)

I hope this information help you.